# could not access internet from kvm virtual machine using bridge network

Tags: networking

I am configure some kvm virtual mahine in my fedora 32, and the virtual machine using bridge network, this is the bridge network configuaration in my host machine:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv network-scripts]$ cat ifcfg-br0 

TYPE=Bridge

BOOTPROTO=static

IPADDR=192.168.1.2

NETMASK=255.255.255.0

GATEWAY=192.168.1.1

DNS1=8.8.8.8

DNS2=114.114.114.114

DEVICE=br0

NAME=br0

ONBOOT=yes
```

and I set the virtual machine's ip:

```
192.168.1.29
192.168.1.30
192.168.1.31
```

I could successfully ping these ip from my host machine 192.168.31.77. but I could not ping 192.168.31.77 from the kvm virtual machine and kvm virtual machine could not access internet. what should I do to make kvm could access internet?

Comment: Please add output of `iptables-save` into your question.

Comment: How did you configure the network in the guest?